# MySQL get sum of fields which rows refer to the two records in another table in between selected rows

Tags: mysql, reference, sum, field, outer-join

Sorry about the vague title, but I'm not quite sure how to name this procedure. So the problem is I have two tables. First one represents train stations and their order:

```
station_id | station_name 
1          |  station1 
2          |  station2 
3          |  station3 
4          |  station4 
5          |  station5 
6          |  station6
```

And the second table represents the price of riding in a train from one station to another(columns `station1_id` and `station2_id` are foreign keys to upper table column `station_id`):

```
price_id | station1_id | station2_id | price 
1        |  1          |  2          |  0.4  
2        |  2          |  3          |  0.35 
3        |  3          |  4          |  0.32 
4        |  4          |  5          |  0.20 
5        |  5          |  6          |  0.25
```

What I want to do is calculate the price of a ticket for someone who wants to take a train from station A to station B. If for example station A  is 'station2' and station B is 'station5', then I want my query to return '0.87'.

Maybe someone could throw in a suggestion on how to solve situations where stations A is after station B i.e. query needs to calculate the price of the ticket going from bottom to top.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(price)
  FROM prices
  WHERE station1_id >= station1 AND station1_id < station2;
```

`station2_id` column is surplus.